# Scene2D UI not filling whole screen

Tags: java, libgdx, scene2d

In the level selection screen I'm currently working on I can't seem to make the Scene2D UI table fill the whole screen.
I've omitted a few bits from the code to reduce the length, but here is the relevant code:

```
Stage stage = new Stage(new ScreenViewport());

table = new Table();
table.setFillParent(true);
innerTable = new Table();
//Omitted: Add a button to innerTable for each level

ScrollPaneStyle scrollPanelStyle = new ScrollPaneStyle();
scrollPanelStyle.vScrollKnob = new BaseDrawable();
scrollPane = new ScrollPane(innerTable);
scrollPane.setScrollingDisabled(true, false);
scrollPane.setupOverscroll(30f, 30f, 150f);

//Temporarily a restart icon 
Image backButton = new Image(backButtonTexture);
backButton.setScaling(Scaling.fit);
table.add(backButton).height(75f).width(75f).pad(20, 0, 20, 0).left();
table.row();
table.add(scrollPane);
```

It currently looks like this. The icon isn't as far to the left as I would think it would be with the current code. As far as I'm concerned it should be at 0 on the X axis.

[image: Level selection screen]

The same thing is true for the innerTable with the ScrollPane containing all the levels, it doesn't fill the entire screen on the X axis, but it looks like I want it, so it's not really a problem there.

**Answer:**
Adding `expandX()` to my ScrollPane ended up doing the trick, resulting in this line: `table.add(scrollPane).expandX();`. A big thanks to flogy.

Comment: As a temporary solution I can use negative padding, but a more proper fix will still be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess the table is stretched properly to your viewport but there is some other misconfiguration. I recommend using the debug mode to get more details (see https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table#debugging - also use on the back button etc). If you can't find a solution using this method by yourself, please update the screenshot, so we can investigate further. Thanks.

**Final solution (see comments):**

```
 table.add(scrollPane).expandX();
```

The table was already filling the whole screen but the contained scroll panel was not. The table cells adapt to their content by default. By using expandX, we could finally expand the width of the cell that contains the scroll panel to the full table width.

Comment: Alright, I added an image where debug mode is on. I used the width() method on the icon, so now it actually goes to the edge, but my problem isn't solved yet, as the edge of the table still isn't filling the whole screen.

Comment: Weird... I can think of two possibilities:
a) the table somehow adapts to the ScrollPane -> take it out and see where the button goes to. If x=0, then the ScrollPane is the problem, if it gets centred, then the setFillParent(true) somehow does not work in your case.
b) The viewport is causing the problem. Maybe it does not scale to the full window size?

Comment: Actually if you look closely, you can see a blue border that fills the entire screen. Doesn't this mean that the outer table is filling the whole space, even if my inner tables aren't? And as for the ScrollPane, removing that results in this: http://i.imgur.com/MpFr07h.png

Comment: Oh, you're right, didn't see that. Then I think this could help: table.add(scrollPane).fillX(); see: https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Table#fill

Comment: `fillX()` didn't work, but I have found something else, based on your answers. It would seem that the edge does indeed fit the contents of the ScrollPane. When I added another column of levels, the edge moved as well.

Comment: Still sounds to me like fillX() or expandX() could help. Have you tried it?

Comment: Ah! `expandX()` did the trick. Thank you very much. I had tried `fillX()`, but  didn't know of `expandX()`.